# Getting JSON from tmi.twitch.tv with Javascript in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, cors, twitch

I am trying to get the resulting JSON of https://tmi.twitch.tv/hosts?include_logins=1&host=105458682 with Javascript in a Chrome Extension, and so far I've had no success.

When I open it in a tab in Google Chrome, I get the following JSON response :

```
{"hosts":[{"host_id":105458682,"target_id":49780445,"host_login":"bobross","target_login":"misscoookiez"}]}
```

But if I try the same call from Javascript (and more precisely a Javascript used in a Chrome extension), I'll get the following error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://tmi.twitch.tv/hosts?include_logins=1&host=113403683. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://deooplkjmdhjdicmeijmecmlnapmjhkd' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The code I used in Javascript is :

```
function callTwitch() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    req.open("GET", "https://tmi.twitch.tv/hosts?include_logins=1&host=105458682" , true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == "200") {
                var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                // Do something with data
            } else {
                // Do something else
            }
        }
    };
    req.send(null);
};
```

After some googling, I found that it's a matter of CORS. Twitch didn't set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`on their server and that's what seems to be blocking me. I tried many different ways of getting that JSON without any success.
I don't understand how and why this JSON is available when getting it from a tab and not when getting it from Javascript...

Can anyone help me ? Is there any way of getting this JSON from Javascript?

Comment: I have re-opened the question, as it wasn't really a duplicate. You can now add your solution as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found how to do cross-origin XMLHttpRequest calls from a Chrome extension : I just had to add "https://tmi.twitch.tv/" to the permissions in manifest.json, and my original code started working. More about that here : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr